# Build static library for iOS (Device and Simulator) and use in XCode

Tags: xcode, ios, ios-simulator, static-libraries

I'm new to XCode-/iOS-Development(not programming itself) and want to make some simple Apps to get used to it.

My current project is a simple QR-Code-Generation. For this task I want to use the Open Source Library libqrencode.
( http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html )
I did not use open source libraries in my older coding projects but I guess I understood most of the "mechanics" ;)

Until now I tried to build the static library and include it in my XCode-Project. But when compiling code using functions from the library I get Error-Messages.

---

**1st Problem:**

I try to build for iPhone-Device like this:

```
#### Build libqrencode for iPhoneOS


export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
export HOST=arm-apple-darwin10
export TARGET=arm-apple-darwin10
export PREFIX=$HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Release-iphoneos

export AR=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar
export CPP=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp
export CXXPP=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2
export LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld
export NM=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/nm
export RANLIB=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --host=$HOST --target=$TARGET --disable-shared --enable-static

makedepend
make
make install
```

But when I include it in my XCode-Project and try to use two simple Functions from that library I get the following error:

```
Ld build/myQRencode.build/Release-iphoneos/myQRencode.build/Objects-normal/armv6/myQRencode normal armv6
cd /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -L/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/libqrencode/Release-iphoneos/lib -F/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/myQRencode.build/Release-iphoneos/myQRencode.build/Objects-normal/armv6/myQRencode.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lqrencode -o /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/myQRencode.build/Release-iphoneos/myQRencode.build/Objects-normal/armv6/myQRencode

ld: warning: in /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/libqrencode/Release-iphoneos/lib/libqrencode.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
Undefined symbols:
  "_QRcode_encodeString", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_QRcode_free", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Ld build/myQRencode.build/Release-iphoneos/myQRencode.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myQRencode normal armv7
cd /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -L/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/libqrencode/Release-iphoneos/lib -F/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/myQRencode.build/Release-iphoneos/myQRencode.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myQRencode.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lqrencode -o /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/myQRencode.build/Release-iphoneos/myQRencode.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myQRencode

ld: warning: in /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/libqrencode/Release-iphoneos/lib/libqrencode.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
Undefined symbols:
  "_QRcode_encodeString", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_QRcode_free", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

---

**2nd Problem:**

I try to build for iPhone-Device like this:

```
#### Build libqrencode for iPhone-Simulator


export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
export HOST=i386-apple-darwin10
export TARGET=i386-apple-darwin10
export PREFIX=$HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator

export AR=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar
export CPP=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp
export CXXPP=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2
export LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld
export NM=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/nm
export RANLIB=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --host=$HOST --target=$TARGET --disable-shared --enable-static

makedepend
make
make install
```

But when I include it in my XCode-Project and try to use two simple Functions from that library I get the following error (actually same error-message like above):

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myQRencode.app/myQRencode normal i386
cd /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib -F/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/myQRencode.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myQRencode.build/Objects-normal/i386/myQRencode.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lqrencode -o /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myQRencode.app/myQRencode

ld: warning: in /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib/libqrencode.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols:
  "_QRcode_encodeString", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_QRcode_free", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Question 1:**
I also tried HOST and TARGET to be set to i686, but that didn't work either (same error message). Unfortunately I only have "i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2" and similar ones, but no "i386-xxxx....". Is this the problem or what settings did I choose wrong?

**Question 2:**
How do I check what target the library was built for? Is there a special command in bash?
I remember when first time building libqrencode I needed to get libpng12. Until now I do not use any commands for creating PNGs but I did not rebuild it for the iPhone-Simulator nor the iPhone-Device. Will the libpng12-library still be linked by XCode and could this consequently be the source of error?

Any help appreciated. Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to be as thorough as possible. Thans allready!!

---

---

**Added Infos:**

I managed to build *libpng12* for I386 using the following Configuration-Settings:

```
#! /bin/bash

#### Build libpng12 for iPhone-Simulator

unset CPATH
unset C_INCLUDE_PATH
unset CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
unset OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
unset LIBS
unset DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
unset DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH

unset CPP
unset CXXPP
unset CC
unset CXX
unset LD
unset STRIP
unset CPPFLAGS
unset CFLAGS
unset CXXFLAGS
unset LDFLAGS
unset AS
unset ASCPP

export SDKVER="4.2"
export DEVROOT="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer"
export SDKROOT="$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator$SDKVER.sdk"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export PREFIX="$HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libpng12/Debug-iphonesimulator"
export AS="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/as"
export ASCPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/as"
export AR="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar"
export RANLIB="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib"
export CPPFLAGS="-miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVER -std=c99 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -I$SDKROOT/usr/include -I$HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libpng12/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/usr/local/iphone-simulator-$SDKVER/include"
export CFLAGS="-miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVER -std=c99 -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp --sysroot='$SDKROOT' -isystem $SDKROOT/usr/include -isystem $HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libpng12/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -isystem /usr/local/iphone-simulator-$SDKVER/include -m32"
export CXXFLAGS="-miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVER -std=c99 -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp --sysroot='$SDKROOT' -isystem $SDKROOT/usr/include -isystem $HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libpng12/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -isystem /usr/local/iphone-simulator-$SDKVER/include"
export LDFLAGS="-miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVER -arch i386 --sysroot='$SDKROOT' -L$SDKROOT/usr/lib -L$HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libpng12/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib -L/usr/local/iphone-simulator-$SDKVER/lib"
export CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp"
export CXXCPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp"
export CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/gcc-4.2"
export CXX="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/g++-4.2"
export LD="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld"
export STRIP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/strip"

./configure --prefix="$PREFIX" --host="i386-apple-darwin9" --enable-static --disable-shared
```

But when I try using similar/same settings for *libqrencode* I get following error:

```
make  all-recursive
Making all in .
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -std=c99 -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp --sysroot='/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk' -isystem /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/include -isystem /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -isystem /usr/local/iphone-simulator-4.2/include -m32 -version-number 3:1:1 -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -arch i386 --sysroot='/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk' -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib -L/usr/local/iphone-simulator-4.2/lib -m32 -o libqrencode.la -rpath /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib qrencode.lo qrinput.lo bitstream.lo qrspec.lo rscode.lo split.lo mask.lo  
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libqrencode.a
libtool: link: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar cru .libs/libqrencode.a  qrencode.o qrinput.o bitstream.o qrspec.o rscode.o split.o mask.o
/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libqrencode.a(bitstream.o) cputype (16777223) does not match previous archive members cputype (7) (all members must match)
/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libqrencode.a(rscode.o) cputype (16777223) does not match previous archive members cputype (7) (all members must match)
/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libqrencode.a(split.o) cputype (16777223) does not match previous archive members cputype (7) (all members must match)
libtool: link: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib .libs/libqrencode.a
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libqrencode.a(bitstream.o) cputype (16777223) does not match previous archive members cputype (7) (all members must match)
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libqrencode.a(rscode.o) cputype (16777223) does not match previous archive members cputype (7) (all members must match)
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libqrencode.a(split.o) cputype (16777223) does not match previous archive members cputype (7) (all members must match)
make[2]: *** [libqrencode.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: While the environment variables look alright, the generated static library seems to not get recognized. Look at the output of the command `otool -hv /Users/johnny/Desktop/MyProjects/myQRencode/libqrencode/Release-iphoneos/lib/libqrencode.a`, does it list `ARM` and `V6` or `V7` in the second and third column of the output ?

Comment: thank you for that tip! NO, it lists "X86_64" for all entries.

So it is obviously some error when building the library, but why? It seems quite obvious I try to define the correct cpuytype (target) with my configuration.
BTW, same for the iPhone-Simulator-Library.

Comment: @EliteTUM: This suggests that it wasn't compiled with `arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2`. You'll need to check the generated `Makefile` (should be in a variable `CC` and/or `CXX`).

Comment: @DarkDust: at the end of `./configure ....` I get `CC       = gcc`and `CXX      = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2`

Comment: @EliteTUM: Do you mean at the end `configure`'s output ? If it's in the Makefile, then try editing it and set `CC=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2`

Comment: BTW, I checked my `libpng12` and it also said `X86_64`. With a little different Configuration-Settings I managed to build it for `I386`. Unfortunately, when trying to use the same for `libqrencide` I get an error. For Details check added Infos at top.

Comment: @DarkDust: In `Makefile`I also have `CC=gcc`. I manually set it to `CC=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2`. As error I then get: `ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libpng12.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)`. For `libpng12.dylib`, `otool -hv`always lists `X86_64`, the `libpng12.a` I manage to build as Ì386` (compare my added infos above). Any ideas how I can build `libpng12.dylib` for `i386`?

(BTW thanks for all your effort allready!!!)

Comment: @EliteTUM: Sorry, not `i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2`, you need to set it to `arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2`.

Comment: @DarkDust: Won't make any difference, will it? Until now I tried to build for i386 (iPhone-Simulator). As soon as it works, building for iOS (arm v6/arm v7) should be easier.

I was able to narrow down the problem to the required library `libpng12.dylib` which I can not manage to build for `i386` nor `arm`. Only the `libpng12.a`, so the static version of it. But how can I build the dynamic `*.dylib`-File for the desired target?

Comment: Since you're not allowed to use dynamic linked libraries on iOS you're fine with the static library.

Comment: @DarkDust: Sorry my error, got confused with some error-messages. Nevertheless, now I tried following steps: 1. `configure` using Code from top-posting under **1st problem**. 2. Open `Makefile` and set `CC=gcc` to `CC=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2` 3. `make clean && makedepend && make`. As error I get, that the file `/usr/include/arm/_types.h` doesn't exist. For example the folder `/usr/include/i386/` exists, but there is no `/usr/include/arm/`. Any ideas?

Comment: @EliteTUM: No, sorry, I'm at a loss here.

Comment: @DarkDust: So embarassing, but I found the error after all: In the end, thanks to all your advice, compiling of the library worked perfectly for the iPhone-Simulator. As stupid as I am, I just forgot to copy it from the path I compiled it into to my Project-Path I load it from (my preferred method so I can share it with friends). So after all, it's working now. Maybe tomorrow I will post the Answer on all the Steps I did, so others can follow them if needed!

Comment: @EliteTUM: Good to hear it's working after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I have time to finish this Question. The problem was solved before, I just used a wrong include Path. The library can be successfully created using some code like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

#### Build libqrencode for iPhone-Simulator

unset CPATH
unset C_INCLUDE_PATH
unset CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
unset OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
unset LIBS
unset DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
unset DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH

export SDKVER="4.2"
export DEVROOT="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer"
export SDKROOT="$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator$SDKVER.sdk"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export PREFIX="$HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator"
export AS="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/as"
export ASCPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/as"
export AR="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar"
export RANLIB="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib"
export CPPFLAGS="-miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVER -std=c99 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -I$SDKROOT/usr/include -I$HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/usr/local/iphone-simulator-$SDKVER/include -m32"
export CFLAGS="-miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVER -std=c99 -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp --sysroot='$SDKROOT' -isystem $SDKROOT/usr/include -isystem $HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -isystem /usr/local/iphone-simulator-$SDKVER/include -m32"
export CXXFLAGS="-miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVER -std=c99 -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp --sysroot='$SDKROOT' -isystem $SDKROOT/usr/include -isystem $HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -isystem /usr/local/iphone-simulator-$SDKVER/include -m32"
export LDFLAGS="-miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVER -arch i386 --sysroot='$SDKROOT' -L$SDKROOT/usr/lib -L$HOME/Desktop/MyProjects/cocoa/libqrencode/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib -L/usr/local/iphone-simulator-$SDKVER/lib -m32"
export CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp"
export CXXCPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp"
export CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/gcc-4.2"
export CXX="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/g++-4.2"
export LD="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld"
export STRIP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/strip"

./configure --prefix="$PREFIX" --host="i386-apple-darwin9" --enable-static --disable-shared
```

Thanks to DarkDust again for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not helping you with your compile problems, but it seems you have a much bigger issue: libqrencode is licensed under LGPL, and many consider it to be [incompatible with Apple's terms](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/lgpl-and-the-iphone.html) ([another article about GPL/LGPL being incompatible with Apple's terms](http://michelf.com/weblog/2011/gpl-ios-app-store/)). So you might put yourself at a legal risk by using libqrencode in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your very eye-opening advice. Once again I'm being reminded how much I hate License-questions :)
But this should be just a (maybe) future problem since for the beginning I did not intend to publish the App in the Apple AppStore. As mentioned above, this partucular project of mine is rather meant as a "Start into working with XCode". Actually I even wanted to publish the whole source code anyway (since most work wasn't mine). But at least I now know that I will not have to think about submitting it to the AppStore in future any longer.

Comment: I've checked with the author and he confirmed that libqrencode can be used under a bsd-style license.  if you make any more on it, i'd kick some back his way